# In Bash for Windows and Powershell, how can I set a hotkey to alternate forward / and back \ on a path on prompt?

Tags: bash, powershell, path

I need to work on MS Windows but have a preference for working in either BASH shell using Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL) or using Powershell. Powershell has a neat feature that if you have written a path using forward `/` at the prompt and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will convert those to back `\`.

While this is convenient sometimes, it can also work against me because I like to run Linux tools in Powershell using `& wsl [linux-tool] [arguments]` (e.g. grep, awk, vim etc.). In that case the Linux tool really expects the forward `/`'s. Similarly, if I copy-paste a path from Windows Explorer into a BASH for WSL terminal, I need to manually convert `\`'s to `/`'s. It would be most convenient if there was a hotkey that could *alternate* between `/`'s and `\`'s on any path supplied at prompt.

Does anyone know the simplest way to do this?

Comment: You can use forward slashes all the time. PowerShell accepts both forward and backslashes as path separators.

Comment: O, I see. Well, that does help some (except for copy-paste). Also when I hit TAB for auto-complete it changes the /s into \s. So then it doesn't work for Linux commands again.